# Python reading adding an empty list while file is finished

Tags: python

I've got a text file with 3 lines:

```
first: 10 3,
second: 11 4,
third: 12 5,
```

Unfortunately, I get "out of range" while trying to append capacities and amounts

```
def read_input(input_file):
    capacities=[]
    amounts=[]
    line = input_file.readline().split()
    while line != '':
        print(line)
        capacities.append(line[0])
        amounts.append(line[1])
        line = input_file.readline().split()
```

I added `print(line)` and discovered that while loop executes even if the next line is empty. Is my condition incorrect? What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: `split()` returns a list, not a string. `line != ''` should be `line != []`

Answer (score 1):

You are using split which returns a list not a string. So you need to change the condition to say

```
while len(line) == 2:
```